# Inject properties externally in a Spring context

Tags: java, spring, properties-file

I have two xml files for my project. The first file is just loaded, some beans are instantiated and calling some methods gives me a username and password. This username and password has to be sent to the second xml file which has a Asynchronous listener configured in it. As soon as I load the context, the listener starts. I want to pass the username and password which I have to this xml before I load it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can acheive this using PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.
Assuming, your springConfigXml1.xml(which has the bean containing the following method) is loaded first and setNamePassword method is executed and then springConfigXml2.xml(which has AsyncListenerClass) is loaded later:

```
    public void setNamePassword(){
        //some code
        PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("property.userName", "username");
        properties.setProperty("property.password", "password");
        configurer.setProperties(properties);
                       //Include below line if you have another 
                       //PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer in springConfigXml2.xml       
                        configurer.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true); 
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext();
        context.addBeanFactoryPostProcessor(configurer);
        context.setConfigLocation("springConfigXml2.xml");
        context.refresh();
        //some code
    }



    springConfigXml2.xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">
        <bean id="asyncListener" class="com.example.AsyncListenerClass">
            <property name="userName" value="${property.userName}"/>
            <property name="password" value="${property.password}"/>
        </bean>
    </beans>
```

But then username and password will be set for context life.

Comment: hi prasad, this works for me. however one small issue, in springConfigXml2.xml, i had added a properties file as below:
`<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"> 
<property name="locations">
<list>
<value>classpath:jndi.properties</value>
</list>
</property>
</bean>`
looks like this is getting overwritten by this. how do i include both?

Comment: Include this in the method:configurer.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);

Comment: Glad, that helped you. This conflict was because the placeholderconfigurer (say p1) set in method is overriding the properties of the one(say p2) set in springConfigXml2.xml. p1 is being loaded before p2 by beanfactorypostprocessor and p1 is overwriting the properties in p2.

Comment: yes, I understood that but didnot know how to not override that. I guess the entire concept you are using is setting the properties to use before loading the context, right?